# Adding an active class to a dynamically generated sidebar nav in Hugo

Tags: hugo

Building a site in Hugo which has a sidebar of navigation links - not defined in the config.toml. It's working nicely - but, I would like to add an ACTIVE class to the LI that sits around the current open page the user is viewing. Current Hugo markup is as below:

```
<nav class="sidebar sidebar-hidden" id="site-sidebar">
      <ul>
        {{ $section := .FirstSection }}
        {{ range sort .Site.Sections.ByTitle }}
          <li class="sidebar-section">
            <a href="{{ .Permalink | relLangURL }}"
               {{ if eq .FirstSection $section }}id="sidebar-focus" class="sidebar-focus"{{end}}>{{ .Title }}</a>
            <div class="sidebar-pages">
              <ul>
                {{ range .Pages.ByTitle }}
                  <li class="sidebar-page">
                    <a href="{{ .Permalink | relLangURL }}">{{ .Name }}</a>
                  </li>
                {{ end }}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        {{ end }}
      </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see - we have an if statement working to add a class "sidebar-focus" to the 1st level LI A - but I need this approach to also work on the 2nd level LI that wraps around the A that is active.

e.g. if Section 2 Child 2 page was open

```
<nav class="sidebar sidebar-hidden" id="site-sidebar">
<ul>

<li class="sidebar-section"><a href="#">Section 1</a>
<div class="sidebar-pages">
<ul>
<li class="sidebar-page"><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
<li class="sidebar-page"><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
<li class="sidebar-page"><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li class="sidebar-section"><a href="#" id="sidebar-focus" class="sidebar-focus">Section 2</a>
<div class="sidebar-pages">
<ul>
<li class="sidebar-page"><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
<li class="sidebar-page ACTIVE"><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
<li class="sidebar-page"><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li class="sidebar-section"><a href="#">Section 3</a>
<div class="sidebar-pages">
<ul>
<li class="sidebar-page"><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
<li class="sidebar-page"><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
<li class="sidebar-page"><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Can anyone help achieve this? I am new to Hugo - so don't know the markup code very well...

Thanks!